# Issuet with div's position - HTML PHP

Tags: php, css, html, icons

I have a customer's list where is possible to tag each one like "Emprendedor", "Creativo" and/or "Detallista". I want to insert the following icon for no-taged customers:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/824/6h1d.png

The problem is the icon's position. I want it next to  label. The code is:

```
<?php
    foreach($customers as $customerKey => $customer){ ?>
    <? $selectedCount = "0"; ?>
      <div class="row customer customer-<?=$customer?>">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 customer-name customer-<?=$customer?>"><a href="http://example.com/admin/xyz.php?dtfr=2013-01-01&dtt=2099-12-31&st=0&Submit=Show%20Report&userid=<?=$customer?>"><?=utf8_encode($customerNames[$customer])?></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><?  
    foreach($tags as $tagKey => $tag){
      $selected=false;
            foreach($customerTags as $customerTagKey => $cTags)
                if($customerTagKey == $customer)
                    foreach($cTags as $cKey => $cTag)
                        if($cTag == $tag){
              $selected=true;
              $selectedCount = $selectedCount + 1;
            }
?><span class="label label-<?=$tag?><?=$selected?" selected":" hidden-print"?> customer-<?=$customer?>" onclick="connect('customer-<?=$customer?>', '<?=$customer?>', '<?=$tag?>');"><?=$tag?></span> <?      
    }?></div>
      </div> <!-- customer-<?=$customer?> row -->
<?
  echo "<div class=\"";
  if($selectedCount == 0){
    echo "glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign glyphicon-red";
  }
  if($selectedCount > 1){
    echo "glyphicon glyphicon-retweet glyphicon-blue";
  }
  echo " \"></div>";
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: so what is the problem that you are facing in placing icon???

Comment: There is really no need for the PHP script here. Maybe if you just show us the output source of the HTML and what you have tried to get the icon in the right place.

Comment: Really it's HTML and CSS we need to see. Or if it's live somewhere then link to that and we can debug to our hearts content.

Comment: Ya, the script is printing the icon in another row below the href. I want it next to href label (Customer's names).

Comment: The code is in the question embedded in php. The script print divs foreach customer in the database, and spans foreach customer's tags.

Comment: Yes we can see that. But this is simply a `HTML / CSS` question. The people that may be able to help you most might have no idea what is going on in that script because they don't know `PHP`. You are going to have to use some CSS styling to get the icon in the right place.

Comment: Strip out the PHP please, or give us a link.